# How to set a URI as a variable depending on if it is in production environment or not

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, heroku

Currently have a MERN app trying to deploy on heroku. I have the mongodb URI declared by importing a config file locallly but on heroku I set up heroku config to use `process.env.mongoURI`. What's a good way to set up my code so that it will use my local config file if it is being run locally and heroku config when it is being run in heroku? Here is what I am trying so far and it doesn't work.

```js
if (process.env) {
  const keys = null
} else {
  const keys = require('./config/keys')
}
```

```js
let db = '';
if (process.env) {
  db = process.env.mongoURI
} else {
  db = keys.mongoURI
}
```

Comment: Maybe using process.env as the conditional argument is not wise? Not exactly sure what/when it appears, just know that it is available when on heroku

Answer (score 1):

Here's how i do it. I create a different config file for different environments. For example:

My config file:

```
const environment = {};

environment.development = {

    mongoURI: 'Your mongo uri',
    port: '5000',
    secret: "YOUR SECRET"
};

environment.production = {

    mongoURI: 'Your mongo uri',
    port: 'YOUR PORT',
    secret: "YOUR SECRET"
};

var currentEnvironment = typeof(process.env.NODE_ENV) == 'string' ? process.env.NODE_ENV.tolower() : "";

var environmentToExport = typeof(environment[currentEnvironment]) == 'string' ? environment[currentEnvironment] : environment.development;

module.exports = environmentToExport;
```

You need to have NODE_ENV set on your local machine as well for this to work.